# Import the OMG provided XMI to an Ecore-Model using genmodel?

Tags: import, uml, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, xmi

The OMG provides XMI-files of the uml [metamodel](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4.1/). However, I want to import these files to an Ecore-model using genmodel.

If I try to load the xmi-files with the genmodel wizard, always the following exception appears. I am using Eclipse Indigo with Eclipse Modeling Framework.

> org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.PackageNotFoundException: Package with uri
>   'http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20110701' not found.
>   (file:/C:/Users/.../UML/UML.xmi, 3,
>   105)  at
>   org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.getPackageForURI(XMLHandler.java:2591)

I seems to me as it is a problem concerning the version of the XMI-files, but I am not sure. I suppose eclipse could not handle XMI 2.4.1. Am I right? If yes, is there a possibility to import XMI 2.4.1 with Eclipse Indigo - EMF?

I have downloaded all xmi-files from the website and dropped them into one folder. Then I had tried to import them and the exception appeared. Has anybody already imported these files into an Ecore-model.
What do I have to pay attention? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you should load the UML Ecore as an external resource of your own Ecore (meta-model). The genmodel will automatically be updated coherently with that